# File name from "Send and Download"

Tags: postman

In Postman, how can I control the name of the file that is downloaded from using the "Send and Download" option? It is always "response" but I want it to be the actual name of the file that is sent over.

Comment: any luck with this, looking to do the same?

Comment: think i remember seeing posts about how the creator "fixed" this issue, but nothing that actually described how to do it

Comment: looking for the same

Comment: They are still "fixing" this... https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2082#event-1624171478

Answer (score 1):

Postman has resolved this issue; by modifying the 'Content-Disposition' response header in your server you can control the name of the downloaded file.

Sample rails code:

```
def show
  if request.headers['Accept'] == 'application/pdf'
    send_data @document.read_file(:pdf)
    # response.headers['Content-Disposition] == "attachment" # send_data sets this initially
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] += '; filename="document.pdf"'
  else
    respond_with @document, params
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Response is not your fault. This issue is being actively worked on. Currently, it will not respect your headers in the response.

You can track this issue here:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2082

Answer (score 0):

I just looked this up in Google and it seems they still haven't  added this option  in Postman.

Here's the Github issue, and it's last updated 4 days ago.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2082

Hope this will be helpful for someone who is coming across this page.